# Milnor fibration and Runge pair

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables, stein-manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{A}^3\to \mathbb{A}^1$ be a polynomial map. Let $0\in \mathbb{A}^1$ be critical value. If $c \in \mathbb{A}^1$ is very close to zero (c is a regular value), then for Milnor fibration we consider a ball $B$ inside $\mathbb{A}^3$ centered at $P$, where $P$ is a critical point in $f^{-1}(0)$ and a small disk $D$ around $0 \in \mathbb{A}^1$ and consider the punctured disk $D^*=D-\{0\}$ and take the restriction $f^{-1}(D^*)\cap B\to D^*$. Then $c\in D^* $. My question is $f^{-1}(c)\cap B \to f^{-1}(c)$ induces injective map in $H_2(-; \mathbb{Q})$ (the singular homology with integral coefficient)? Can I show the pair $\{f^{-1}(c), f^{-1}(c)\cap B\}$ is a Runge pair?